# Dynamically create columns from string with delimiter in Spark

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, multiple-columns

I have a table like this:

```
a |  a_vector                               |  
1 | 710.83;-776.98;-10.86;2013.02;-896.28;  |  
2 | 3  ; 2  ;  1                            |
```

Using PySpark/pandas, how do I dynamically create columns so that first values in vector go to "col1" and second values go to "col2" etc. + calculate the sum?

```
a |  a_vector                               |  col1 | col2   | col3
1 | 300;-200;2022;                          |  300  |  -200  | 2022
2 | 3  ; 2  ;  1                            |   3   |  2     | 1
```

The final requirement is to have the sums of new columns sorted in one column.

Comment: is your end objective just to add the values? or would you need the new columns for other purposes as well?

Comment: is it a pandas or pyspark question ? cause that's not the same thing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PySpark, you can do it by first splitting your string on `;` (creating an array) and then selecting columns using list comprehension. The sum can be calculated using [`aggregate`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.aggregate.html#pyspark.sql.functions.aggregate) higher-order function.

Input:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('1', '300;-200;2022'),
     ('2', '3  ; 2  ;   1')],
    ['a', 'a_vector']
)
```

Script:

```py
col_arr = F.split('a_vector', '\s*;\s*')
max_size = df.agg(F.max(F.size(col_arr))).head()[0]
df = df.select(
    '*',
    *[col_arr[i].alias(f'col{i}') for i in range(max_size)],
    F.aggregate(col_arr, F.lit(0.0), lambda acc, x: acc + x).alias('sum')
)

df.show()
# +---+-------------+----+----+----+------+
# |  a|     a_vector|col0|col1|col2|   sum|
# +---+-------------+----+----+----+------+
# |  1|300;-200;2022| 300|-200|2022|2122.0|
# |  2|3  ; 2  ;   1|   3|   2|   1|   6.0|
# +---+-------------+----+----+----+------+
```

Based on the comments, the following is probably what you need. Calculating max_size of array elements, calculating column-wise sums and sorting the results.

```py
col_arr = F.split('a_vector', '\s*;\s*')
max_size = df.agg(F.max(F.size(col_arr))).head()[0]
df = df.agg(F.array_sort(F.array([F.sum(col_arr[i]) for i in range(max_size)])).alias('sum'))

df.show(truncate=0)
# +-----------------------+
# |sum                    |
# +-----------------------+
# |[-198.0, 303.0, 2023.0]|
# +-----------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

with names

```
dfs = df['a_vector'].str.split(';', expand=True).rename(columns = lambda x: "col"+str(x+1))
df =pd.concat([df, dfs], axis=1)
print(df)
```

inputs

```
   a       a_vector
0  1  300;-200;2022
1  2          3;2;1
```

Output

```
   a       a_vector col1  col2  col3
0  1  300;-200;2022  300  -200  2022
1  2          3;2;1    3     2     1
```

Note: Not tested..Let me know if deosn't work

Comment: Thanks, how could I sum col1,col2,col3 dynamically too I ask after I have second output?  newdf = df.sum(columns = lambda x: "col"+str(x+1))

Comment: You mean you want to sum col1,col2,col3 ?...Like 300+(-200)+2022 = 2122?