# reduce array column by element-wise sum in spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a DataFrame in PySpark with a column "c1" where each row consists of an array of integers

| c1 |
| --- |
| 1,2,3 |
| 4,5,6 |
| 7,8,9 |

I wish to perform an element-wise sum (i.e just regular vector addition) over this column to reduce it to the single array [12, 15, 18].

What I would want is something akin to
`df.select(sum("c1"))`
but which performs vector/array addition over the chosen column.

When searching I mostly find various
`zip_with`
and higher-order function solutions that assume I have multiple columns and wish to add rows together. Perhaps I haven't been able to word it right.

EDIT: the c1 column is just an example for ease of writing. I really have a column with a couple thousand entries, where each array has a couple hundred elements.

---

**Solution**

With help from notNull I managed to come up with this solution:

```
# out of bounds array elements will be set to null
max_elements = df_mv_pr.select(max(size("movement_profile"))).first()[0]

# Create a list of column expressions to be used in the select statement
selected_cols = [sum(col("c1")[i]).alias("elem_"+str(i)) for i in range(max_elements )]

df_new = df.select(array(*selected_cols).alias(sum))
```

Comment: What is c1 column type.. is it array (or) string?

Comment: the column type of c1 is an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the array to three columns then use `groupBy` to create a `sum(array)`.

**`Example:`**

```
df.withColumn("temp1", col("temp")[0]).\
    withColumn("temp2", col("temp")[1]).\
      withColumn("temp3", col("temp")[2]).\
        groupBy(lit("1")).agg(array(sum(col("temp1")),sum(col("temp2")),sum(col("temp3"))).cast("array<int>").alias("sum")).\
          drop("1").\
            show()
#+------------+
#|         sum|
#+------------+
#|[12, 15, 18]|
#+------------+
```

Comment: I should perhaps have clarified that the column I gave was just an example and that I'm really working with a couple thousand entries where each array have a couple hundred of elements each. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Sure, you can dynamically split the arrays to create columns using this process. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74361797/dynamically-create-columns-from-string-with-delimiter-in-spark

Comment: Thank you! I managed to solve my problem with your help. I'll update my question with the solution I found.

Answer (score 0):

If you have arrays with different lengths per key column, there are ways to do it without converting to columns.

They are all a bit clunky, though.

You could use them like this:

```py
df.groupBy('my_key_column').agg(sum_arrays('my_array_column'))
```

#### pyspark.ml.stat.Summarizer

This seems fastest for my use case, but it seems not not be able to handle `NULL` elements in the arrays.
It will do some aggregation *before* shuffling.

```py
    from pyspark.ml.stat import Summarizer
    from pyspark.ml.functions import array_to_vector, vector_to_array

    def sum_arrays(col):
        return vector_to_array(Summarizer.sum(array_to_vector(col)))
```

#### Spark SQL `collect_list` + `aggregate`

Note all of the data is shuffled (for `collect_list`), before `aggregate` is applied after the shuffle.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, types as T

def sum_arrays(col, sum_type=T.ArrayType(T.DoubleType())):
    return F.aggregate(
        F.collect_list(col),
        F.lit(None).cast(sum_type),  # we _have_ to provide an initialValue
        lambda accumulator, array_row: (
            F.when(accumulator.isNull(), array_row)  # handle initialValue.
            .otherwise(F.zip_with(accumulator, array_row, lambda a, b: a + b))
        )
    )
```

#### Pandas User Defined Function

This also shuffles all the data before it does aggregation.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf
from pyspark.sql.functions import PandasUDFType

@pandas_udf(T.ArrayType(T.DoubleType()), PandasUDFType.GROUPED_AGG)
def sum_arrays(v: pd.Series):
    return v.sum()
```